# Фоновый процесс для приложения работающего на смартфоне с версией android 6.0 и выше

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения, android-broadcastreceiver

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть приложение которое принимает сообщения (в том числе и в фоновом режиме (т.е. когда закрыто или свёрнуто)). На смартфоне с версией android 5.1.1 приложение работает нормально, т.е. сообщения в фоновом режиме поступают, а вот на  android версии 7.1 нет. Требуются ли прописывать запрос к пользователю, предоставить возможность работать приложению работать в фоновом режиме, если да то как это сделать (конкретно разрешение для работы приложения в фоновом режиме)? Если нет, то какие могут быть варианты решения данной проблемы?

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.danil.smssecurity">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Acrans.Acr.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran0_1" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran1" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran2" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran3" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran4" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran5" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran6" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran7" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran8" />
        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran2_2" />

        <receiver android:name=".Acrans.ForSms.MessageReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".Acrans.Acr.acran4_1"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

MessageReceiver.java

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG="myLogs";
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    public static  String writeNameNumer [];
    com.example.danil.smssecurity.Acrans.Acr.acran1 acran1=new acran1();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        dbHelper=new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus != null ? pdus.length : 0];
            String phone="";
            String message="";
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) (pdus != null ? pdus[i] : null));
                //1-адресс приходс сообщения
                str += messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += ": ";
                //2-само сообщение
                str += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                str += "\n";

                phone=messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                message=messages[i].getMessageBody();
                Cursor cur = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_MESSAGE, new String[] {"_id", DBHelper.MESS_PHONE}, null, new String[] {}, null, null, null);
                boolean k=cur.moveToFirst();

                if (k==false) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "база пуста");

                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.MESS_PHONE, phone);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.MESS_MESSAGE, message);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.MESS_MARCER, "me");
                    database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_MESSAGE, null, contentValues);



                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", str);
                    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                } else  {
                    Log.i(TAG, "база не пуста");
//                    database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, DBHelper.KEY_ID, null);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.MESS_PHONE, phone);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.MESS_MESSAGE, message);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.MESS_MARCER, "me");
                    database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_MESSAGE, null, contentValues);



                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", str);
                    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                }


                String searchNomer="";
                char one=phone.toCharArray()[0];
                String sim= Character.toString(one);
                contentValues = new ContentValues();
                if (sim.equals("+")){
                    searchNomer=phone.substring(2);
                } else {
                    if ((sim.equals("7"))|(sim.equals("8"))) {
                        searchNomer=phone.substring(1);
                    }
                }
                int col=0;
                one=phone.toCharArray()[0];
                sim= Character.toString(one);

                Zamena_nomera_na_name(searchNomer, sim, phone, context);

                if ((sim.equals("+"))|(sim.equals("7"))|(sim.equals("8"))){
                    if ((phone.length()>10)&(phone.length()<=12)){

                Cursor zxcv = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NUMBER, new String[] {}, DBHelper.NUM_PHONE + " LIKE ?" , new String[] {"%"+searchNomer}, null, null, null);
                if (zxcv.moveToFirst()) {
                    int countIndex=zxcv.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NUM_COUNT);
                    int phoneIndex = zxcv.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.NUM_PHONE);
                    do {
                        Log.i(TAG, "phone = " + zxcv.getString(phoneIndex));
                        try {
                            col=Integer.parseInt(zxcv.getString(countIndex));
                            col++;
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            col=1;
                        }
                        database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_NUMBER, DBHelper.NUM_PHONE +" LIKE ?" , new String[] {"%"+searchNomer});
                        Log.i(TAG, "запись успешно удалена");

                    } while (zxcv.moveToNext());
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG,"0 rows");
                    col=1;
                }
                zxcv.close();


                        contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        contentValues.put(DBHelper.NUM_PHONE, this.writeNameNumer[1]);
                        contentValues.put(DBHelper.NUM_NAME, this.writeNameNumer[0]);
                        contentValues.put(DBHelper.NUM_COUNT, col);
                        database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_NUMBER, null, contentValues);
                    }
                }


                String KEY="";
                Cursor rebol = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH}, DBHelper.KEY_PHONE + " LIKE ?" , new String[] {"%"+searchNomer}, null, null, null);
                if (rebol.moveToFirst()) {
                    int keyInd = rebol.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH);
                    do {
                        KEY =rebol.getString(keyInd);
                    } while (rebol.moveToNext());
                } else {
                    contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PHONE, this.writeNameNumer[1]);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH, R.string.defaultKey);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_NAME, this.writeNameNumer[0].toLowerCase());
                    database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);
                    Log.i(TAG,"0 rows");}
                rebol.close();

                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            abortBroadcast();

        }
    }

    //    замена номера на имя при сохранение в поле editText
    public void Zamena_nomera_na_name(String searchNomer, String sim, String phone, Context context) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Message Receiver замена номера на имя");
        this.writeNameNumer=new String [2];
        dbHelper=new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        try {
            if ((sim.equals("+"))|(sim.equals("7"))|(sim.equals("8"))){
                if ((phone.length()>10)&(phone.length()<=12)){

                    Cursor zxcv = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {}, DBHelper.KEY_PHONE + " LIKE ?" , new String[] {"%"+searchNomer}, null, null, null);
                    if (zxcv.moveToFirst()) {
                        int phoneIndex = zxcv.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_PHONE);
                        int nameIndex=zxcv.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME);
                        do {
                            this.writeNameNumer[0]=zxcv.getString(nameIndex);
                            this.writeNameNumer[1]=zxcv.getString(phoneIndex);


                        } while (zxcv.moveToNext());
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG,"0 rows");

                    }
                    zxcv.close();

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Message Receiver ошибка при замене номера на имя");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Нужно запрашивать разрешения в рантайме на всё перечисленное в [таблице](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups). Как это делать: [Request App Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: Скорей всего у Вас не отрабатывает BroadcastReceiver. Проверьте, метод onReceive отрабатывает?

Comment: targetSDK какой?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja всм версия то 26

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko метод onReceiver отрабатывает.....у меня на смартфоне с android версией 5.1.1 сообщения приходят в фоновом режиме а на смартфоне версии 7.1 нет

Comment: Я спрашивал конкретно на 7.1 (когда не приходят смс) метод onReceive() - отрабатывает?